# How to create an array or object of variables by looking them in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating some JS variables on a Twig template and I am prefixing them with a dynamic value. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    quoteGridId = 'grid_quote';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    quoteContactGridId = 'grid_quote_contact';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    archiveGridId = 'grid_archive';
</script>
```

I need to be able to use them in a Javascript file included after the page loads. How can I create an array of values containing all the *GridId vars?

I would like to be able to use the following on the script:

```
[
    'quoteGridId' => 'grid_quote',
    'quoteContactGridId' => 'grid_quote_contact',
    'archiveGridId' => 'grid_archive',
]
```

**UPDATE:**

Let's try to get my problem clear for those ones opened to help. Currently I am working on a legacy system. Such system had a grid generating a `gridId` value and at the end a JS file was included and such file was using the var `gridId` to perform several things.

Now I need to replicate more than one grid on the same page and that becomes a problem since two grids are generating the same var name:

```
gridId = 'something';
gridId = 'something1';
```

When the script try to reach the `gridId` var is getting always the latest one (something1) and therefore no actions are being taken on the first grid.

My solution was to prefix the name to each `gridId` resulting on what I've as OP. Ex:

somethingGridId = 'something';
   something1GridId = 'something1';

What I am trying to find is a way to re-use the main JS file by passing those dynamic gridIds but I can't find a way to get this to work.

The only solution I've in mind is to create the same file per grid and then change the value of gridId to the name of the ID to be used ....

I am open to ideas, any?

Comment: You mean `window["quoteGridId"]` ?

Comment: @mplungjan not sure if that will help me, I am showing only three as an example but could be more than that

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just create the array in the Twig template? `var gridvars = ['grid_archive', 'grid_quote_contact', 'grid_archive'];`. Then you can just pass `window.gridvars` to your script.

Comment: @CharlieMartin take a look to the UPDATE maybe that will clear a little bit what I am asked in first.

Comment: Update doesn't really help clarify why you can't put these in an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the window variables with regex expressions (regular expression expressions?) i.e.`/.+GridId/` matches any word or variable that ends in `GridId` you can then iterate over them as you wish.

**Example:**

```js
var pattern = /.+GridId/;
GridIds = []
for (var varName in window) {
    if (pattern.test(varName)) {
        GridIds.push({varName:window[varName]})
    }
}
console.log(GridIds);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    quoteGridId = 'grid_quote';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    quoteContactGridId = 'grid_quote_contact';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    archiveGridId = 'grid_archive';
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `quoteGridId = 'grid_quote'`, why don't you create a top level object and then assigning each var as a key-val pair, like:

```
var gridData = {}
gridData.quoteGridId = 'grid_quote'
gridData.quoteContactGridId = 'grid_quote_contact';
/* etc assignments */

//Access your data points like so in a loop, if you choose
Object.keys(gridData).forEach(key => {
   const val = gridData[key]
   //User `key`, and `val` however you'd like
})
```

Comment: take a look to the UPDATE maybe that will clear a little bit what I am asked in first I don't think your way will work either

Answer (score 0):

i think you have you use List. 
each time you push you value to the list like that :

```
var myList = [];
myList.push('something');
myList.push('something1');
```

now you cann access to all of them like that :

```
console.log(myList[0]);
console.log(myList[1]);
```

or just last :

```
console.log(myList[myList.length - 1])
```